# Keyboard sequence shortcuts for menu

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

I wish to have a sequence shortcut for the program I'm developing (in C# .net) to access various buttons in the menu system.

For example:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

First, the user would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, followed by <kbd>O</kbd>

Visual studio uses this method for quite a few of it's menu shortcuts.

When I am editing a menu however, I'm limited to only one shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> or just <kbd>O</kbd>, I cannot sequence them.

Is this possible to do with the existing framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you could do this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (previousKeyEvent != null)
  {
    if (previousKeyEvent.Modifiers == Keys.Control && previousKeyEvent.KeyCode == Keys.W && e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + W then O");
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Not handled");
      previousKeyEvent = null;
    }
  else
    previousKeyEvent = e;
  }
}
```

**Things to consider**

- Single key combinations - Handling those without the scope of a
  previous key event.
- A label for showing that you are awaiting the
  user input, just like visual studio.
- Using the ShortCutKeyDisplayString property to show the custom shortcut next to the menu item.

Comment: This unfortunately would take a lot more effort to implement than i am willing to make. I would have considered however, if not for the fact that in the menu, this does not show it as the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Randomman159 If your not willing to make a level of effort to achieve something that you need to do - as a developer your not probably not going to get very far with many tasks that you set yourself.

Comment: That is hardly what i meant. I'll try to rephrase.

One of the priorities in this problem, is displaying the shirtcut next to the item in the menu, so when a user repetitively uses it, they'll have the shortcut right there for them to see. As your solution, does not incorporate this priority, if i were to implement it, it would only be temporary. Given the large (very large) amount of combination keys neccessary, it seems like an unideal amount of work for a temporary solution.

If there is a way to modify the displayed shortcuts in the menu at runtime however, this solution would be great.

Comment: ahhhh item.ShortcutKeyDisplayString lets you change what it displays.
Thus making your answer a perfectly vauable solution. Thankyou :)